# Defining abstract classes on module.exports call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, abstract-class

I have a basic migration class that looks like this:

```
"use strict";

var Schema   = require('../database/schema');
var sequence = require('when/sequence');
var _        = require('lodash');

class Migrate {

    constructor(knex) {
        this.knex = knex;
    }

    createTable(tableName) {
        ...
    }

    createTables() {
        ...
    }

    run() {
        return this.createTables();
    }
}

module.exports = (knex) => {
    return new Migrate(knex)
}
```

and I can use it like so:

```
require('./app/commands/' + process.argv[2] + '.js')(knex)
    .run()
    .then((...))
```

However, I want to inherit from an abstract class called "Command", so I add the following lines to my "Migrate" class.

```
"use strict";
var Command  = require('./command');

class Migrate extends Command {
     ...
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how I can convert my Command class to a module. Right now it is like this:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = class Command {
    sayHello() {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. (e.g this becomes undefined on Migrate class' constructor method so I cannot put Knex to the instance)

Is there any proper way to use abstract classes with module pattern?

Thank you.

Comment: see this [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) doc !

Comment: @Jérôme Super has nothing to do with my question.